# SugarCRM element cannot be found with Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sugarcrm

I was automating a SugarCRM platform, but the Search and Select field is not clickable when running this with selenium.

[image: with selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9EE8.png)

However this what it really looks like when normally or manually open the page.

[image: opening the page normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwNMk.png)

Did I just missed something?

Comment: can you show some of your work please ?

Comment: This is what i have so far:


driver.findElement(By.linkText("Select Account...")).click();

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Select Account..."))
.sendKeys("Selenium Test Account");

Comment: And error which u are getting ?

Comment: is it taking time to load